# Зацикливание в структуре While

Tags: c

Почему при введении в си вместо цифры, любую букву или в значении вместо запятой точку указать в дробных происходит зацикливание программы?
Пример программы:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

main()
{
      setlocale (LC_ALL, "rus");

      int number_account = 0;
      float start_balance, TotalCost, TotalCredit, ExtendOfCredit, NewBalance, Balance;

      while (number_account != -1)
      {
         printf("Number account - ");
         scanf("%d", &number_account);
         printf("start_balance: ");
         scanf("%f", &start_balance);  
         printf("TotalCost: ");
         scanf("%f", &TotalCost);
         printf("TotalCredit: ");
         scanf("%f", &TotalCredit);
         printf("ExtendOfCredit: ");
         scanf("%d", &ExtendOfCredit);
         NewBalance = start_balance + TotalCost - TotalCredit;

         if (NewBalance > ExtendOfCredit)
         {
            printf("number_account: %d", number_account);
            printf("ExtendOfCredit: %.2f", ExtendOfCredit);
            printf("Balance: %.2f\n \n", Balance = start_balance + TotalCredit);
         }
      }
      system("PAUSE");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[[[[@steelhouse](/users/9264/steelhouse)](/users/9264/steelhouse)](/users/9264/steelhouse)](/users/9264/steelhouse), всегда надо проверять значение, возвращаемое **каждым** `scanf()` (см. `man 3 scanf`, но в Вашем случае нормально - это 1) и правильно программировать обработку ошибок.

**UPD**

[[[[@steelhouse](/users/9264/steelhouse)](/users/9264/steelhouse)](/users/9264/steelhouse)](/users/9264/steelhouse), как обещал о `scanf`.

Эта функция пытается ввести заказанное количество аргументов (в соответствии с форматом) и возвращает количество *успешно* прочитанных аргументов либо EOF (в случае конца входного потока (файла)).

При чтении числа `scanf` сначала пропускает разделители (пробел, табуляция, символ новой строки и т.п.), а затем преобразует цепочку цифр в десятичное число (естественно, знак + или - допускается). Как только встречается **не цифра** `scanf` переходит к чтению следующего аргумента, **но эта "не цифра" остается в потоке!!!**.

Поэтому-то у Вас программа и зацикливается. Вы читаете числа и если встретилась буква (или другой, неподходящий по формату символ), то он остается. Следующий `scanf` пытается читать его и тоже оставляет в потоке и т.д.

Решение состоит в анализе числа, *возвращаемого* `scanf`. Если оно меньше ожидаемого (и не EOF (по EOF видимо надо завершать весь ввод)), то надо **пропустить все символы до новой строки**.

Вот небольшой пример

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// прочтем все символы до новой строки
// вернем (для любопытных) их количество
// или EOF (для анализа конца файла (это уже не пустое любопытство))
static int 
skip() 
{
  int c, n = 0;

  if (!feof(stdin)) // убедимся, что нужно читать
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
      n++;
      if (c == '\n')
        return n;
    }
  return EOF;
}

int
main ()
{
  int a, b, i = 0, rc;

  while (rc !=  EOF) {
    printf ("Enter a,b: "); fflush(stdout);
    rc = scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);
    printf ("rc = %d  a = %d b = %d\n", rc,a,b);
#if ERRDEMO
    if (rc == 2)
      i = 0;
    else if (++i > 5)
      break;
#else
    if (rc != EOF)
      if (rc != 2) {
        printf ("Input error rc = %d\n",rc);
        printf ("skip %d characters\nTry again ",rc = skip());
      }
#endif
  }

  exit (0);
}
```

#if ERRDEMO

#else ...

#endif

это (если Вы еще не знаете) директивы условной компиляции. Т.е. если откомпилировать

```
gcc a.c
```

то скомпилируется код между #else и #endif, а если

```
gcc -DERRDEMO a.c
```

то код между #if и #else. Естественно, код вне #if .... #endif компилируется всегда.

Теперь посмотрите результаты (а также можете собрать ее и под виндой (gcc проверял) и попробовать разные варианты)

```
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ gcc a.c -DERRDEMO
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ ./a.out 
Enter a,b: 1 2
rc = 2  a = 1 b = 2
Enter a,b: 3 a
rc = 1  a = 3 b = 2
Enter a,b: rc = 0  a = 3 b = 2
Enter a,b: rc = 0  a = 3 b = 2
Enter a,b: rc = 0  a = 3 b = 2
Enter a,b: rc = 0  a = 3 b = 2
Enter a,b: rc = 0  a = 3 b = 2
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ gcc a.c
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ ./a.out 
Enter a,b: 1 2
rc = 2  a = 1 b = 2
Enter a,b: 3 a
rc = 1  a = 3 b = 2
Input error rc = 1
skip 2 characters
Try again Enter a,b: 3 4
rc = 2  a = 3 b = 4
Enter a,b: 5 6f
rc = 2  a = 5 b = 6
Enter a,b: rc = 0  a = 5 b = 6
Input error rc = 0
skip 2 characters
Try again Enter a,b: 5 6
rc = 2  a = 5 b = 6
Enter a,b: rc = -1  a = 5 b = 6
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$
```

rc = -1 в конце, это печать по EOF (^D в *nix, ^Z в винде).

Успехов.

**UPD 2**

Немного подправил `skip()` для более правильной работы при вводе с клавиатуры.

Comment: Извините, я только начал обучение программированию, и я немного не понял что именно означает см. man 3 scanf. и как правильно программировать обработку ошибок ещё не умею, вернее вообще ещё до этого не дошёл.

Comment: Почитайте справку. [1][1] [2][2] [3][3]


[1]:http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/
[2]:http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=scanf&category=3&russian=0
[3]:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9y6s16x1.aspx

Comment: @steelhouse, судя по комментарию Вы обучаетесь в винде. Советую перейти на линукс, будет проще.

В любом случае в гугле можно набрать

    man функция

и читать по ссылкам.

--

По теме вопроса: думаю в ближайшее время дополню ответ примером.

Comment: Спасибо большое, порчитаю, на счёт смены ос то пока что думаю, я просто ставил ubuntu 12 и немного не удобна оказалась..
Попробую на виртуальной поставить, посмотрю насколько это лучше.

Comment: Лучше ставь Xubuntu или Mint. Графическое окружение Unity, которое по умолчанию стоит в простой убунте, на мой взгляд, тоже очень неудобно. А в остальном система очень хороша, особенно для начинающих.

Comment: @steelhouse, поставить Xubuntu под VirtualBox (например) это правильно. Если ресурсы host-машины позволяют, то можно поставить одну 32, а другую 64 разряда. Плюс винда в хосте. Уже три (немного разные) среды для программирования. 

Ubuntu с нормальным интерфейсом (насколько я понимаю) это 10.04 (кстати, LTS). Вообще, есть где потренироваться (в написании переносимых программ)!

Comment: Спасибо большое, не ожидал таких подробных сведений. Поставлю Xubuntu, благо "laptop" позволяет, на счёт программирования, пока сложно ещё в уме всё это представить, учусь только азам, до функций и работы с ними не дошёл, всё ещё впереди.